# Why with BasedOnStyle: Google every time I copy/paste it "adds" a indentation?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, formatting

Here's my settings:

```
{
    "C_Cpp.errorSquiggles": "Enabled",
    "C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngine": "Default",
    "C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngineFallback": "Disabled",
    "C_Cpp.clang_format_fallbackStyle": "{ BasedOnStyle: Google, IndentWidth: 4, ColumnLimit: 0}",

    "workbench.sideBar.location": "right",

    "files.exclude": {
        "**/.git": true,
        "**/.svn": true,
        "**/.hg": true,
        "**/CVS": true,
        "**/.DS_Store": true
    },

    "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
    "editor.formatOnType": true,

    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:/msys64/usr/bin/bash.exe", 
    "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": [ "-i" ],
    "terminal.integrated.env.windows": { 
        "MSYSTEM": "MINGW64", 
        "PATH" : "/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/c/Windows/System32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/"
    }
}
```

It correctly format braces as:

```
void myCode() {
}
```

and not:

```
void myCode() 
{
}
```

but when I copy/paste, it also add a new indention, such as:

```
    void myCode() {
    }
```

Expecially when there are some code before this.

Why? How can i fix it?

EDIT: here's a practical example. This is the code I have:

```
struct Test : Module 
    {
    enum ParamIds {
        TRIGGER_PARAM,
        CYCLE_PARAM,        
        RATE_PARAM,
        RATE_FINE_PARAM,
        RISE_LENGTH_PARAM,
        NUM_PARAMS
    };
    enum InputIds 
    {
        TRIGGER_INPUT,

        TAIL_LENGTH_CV_INPUT,
        NUM_INPUTS
    };
    enum OutputIds {
        EOR_OUTPUT, 
        EOF_OUTPUT,
        EOC_OUTPUT,
        RISING_OUTPUT,          
        FALLING_OUTPUT,     
        OUT_OUTPUT,
        NUM_OUTPUTS
    };
};
```

If now within `InputIds` I paste a value in that empty space, that's the result:

```
struct Test : Module 
    {
    enum ParamIds {
        TRIGGER_PARAM,
        CYCLE_PARAM,        
        RATE_PARAM,
        RATE_FINE_PARAM,
        RISE_LENGTH_PARAM,
        NUM_PARAMS
    };
        enum InputIds {
            TRIGGER_INPUT,
            ASD_PARAM,
            TAIL_LENGTH_CV_INPUT,
            NUM_INPUTS
        };
        enum OutputIds {
        EOR_OUTPUT, 
        EOF_OUTPUT,
        EOC_OUTPUT,
        RISING_OUTPUT,          
        FALLING_OUTPUT,     
        OUT_OUTPUT,
        NUM_OUTPUTS
    };
};
```

As you can see, it adds a tab and mess the whole code.

Comment: I assume that you don't paste inside a block (like a class or namespace)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm pasting inside an enum right now (which is inside a struct, etc)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: check the example I've posted. I past because I need some new values (not function), and it will be spaced right messing up che code.